# Shell: Sed -i.bak to rename file by appending current date

Tags: shell, date, sed, backup, file-rename

I have sed statement to replace few contents in my file. It is taking a backup copu with the name `file.bak` before replacing the content.

```
sed -i.bak -r "s#^(.*/abc_def_APP/).*(/application1\.war.*)#\1$version1/$version2\2#" /path/file
```

But I want the file to be backed up with current date. something like `file.071913`

How can I get it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since we have `date "+%m%d%y"` that returns MMDDYY (month day year):

```
$ date "+%m%d%y"
071913
```

What about saying `sed -i.$(this command)` so you have the following?

```
sed -i.$(date "+%m%d%y") -r .... file
```